# How do I use knockoutjs with ScriptSharp?

Tags: knockout.js, script#

As I have just learnt the Script# that I don't know how to use knockoutjs with ScriptSharp. I tried to read through the KnockoutAPI but I am still confused how to write even just a view Model containing just few knockout Observables and how to use the basic function like GetValue and SetValue.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Yup, I googled "knockoutjs ScriptSharp" for several times but I still can't find a simple code for me as a reference. Please excuse for my stupid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel {

    public Observable<string> firstName = Knockout.Observable<string>("Bob");
}

public static class App {

    static App() {
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        Knockout.ApplyBindings(vm);
    }
}
```

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: NikhilK has written an example Hello World using Knockout with Script#: https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/samples/KOWorld